# Pandas date_range starting from the end date to start date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

In am trying to generate a range of semi-annual dates using Python. `Pandas` provides a function [`pd.date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) to help with this however I would like my date range to start from the end date and iterate backwards.

**For instance given the input:**

```
start = datetime.datetime(2016 ,2, 8)
end = datetime.datetime(2018 , 6, 1)
pd.date_range(start, end, freq='6m')
```

**The result is:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-02-29', '2016-08-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-08-31',
               '2018-02-28'])
```

**How can I generate the following:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-02-08', '2016-06-01', '2016-12-01', '2017-06-01',
               '2017-12-01', '2018-06-01'])
```

Comment: Removed my initial answer. I think the main thing here is the offset, is that right?

Comment: @Maximilian yeah that's another way to put it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the updated output (from the edit you made) you can do something like the following:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

end = datetime.datetime(2018 , 6, 1)
start = datetime.datetime(2016 ,2, 8)
#Get the range of months to cover
months = (end.year - start.year)*12 + end.month - start.month
#The frequency of periods
period = 6 # in months

pd.DatetimeIndex([end - DateOffset(months=e) for e in range(0, months, period)][::-1]).insert(0, start)
```

This is a fairly concise solution, though I didn't compare runtimes so I'm not sure how fast it is.

Basically this is just creating the dates you need as a list, and then converting it to a datetime index.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without *pandas* and using *datutil* instead.  However it is more involved than it perhaps should:

```
from datetime import date
import math
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#set up key dates
start = date(2016 ,2, 8)
end = date(2018 , 6, 1)

#calculate date range and number of 6 month periods
daterange = end-start
periods = daterange.days *2//365

#calculate next date in sequence and check for year roll-over
next_date = date(start.year,math.ceil(start.month/6)*6,1)
if next_date < start: next_date = date(next_date.year+1,next_date.month,1)

#add the first two values to a list
arr = [start.isoformat(),next_date.isoformat()]

#calculate all subsequent dates using 'relativedelta'
for i in range(periods):
    next_date = next_date+ relativedelta(months=+6)
    arr.append(next_date.isoformat())


#display results
print(arr)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float` on the `next_date =` line.

Comment: @pyCthon which next_date line is it? The first one or the one in the for loop? If the later, then it could be that you don't have dateutil installed, which I should have mentioned.

Comment: The first one, dateutil is installed, I have `'2.4.2'`

Comment: ah okay try using integer division i.e. start.month//6